# Why Does TypeScript Mapped Type Return an Array for Tuples Instead of an Object?

Tags: typescript

type T1 is Tuple, T2 is Object. but I think their implementation methods are the same.

```
type Tup = ['a','b']
 
 
 type Options <T>  = {
  [K in keyof T]: 1
 }
type T1 = Options<Tup>   //  type T1 = [1, 1]

type keys1 = keyof Tup
type T2 = {
  [K in keys1] :1
}
/**
 * type T2 = {
    [x: number]: 1;
    [Symbol.iterator]: 1;
    0: 1;
    1: 1;
    [Symbol.unscopables]: 1;
    length: 1;
    ...
    }
 */
```

I want to know how TypeScript handles these two types separately, and what is the reason for this

Comment: In `T1`, TypeScript knows that `T` is a tuple, so the result should be a tuple. In `T2`, TypeScript only has the keys to work with and doesn't know that it is supposed to be a tuple.

Comment: It has to do with whether the mapped type is *homomorphic*.  A homomorphic mapped generic like `type F<T> = {[K in keyof T]: ⋯}` will map tuples to tuples, but a non-homomorphic type will not.  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.